# Chrome extension options not always displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension and I've an options page.
This page is an overlay in the [chrome://settings](http://chrome://extensions/) as described in the documentation.
The problem is that my page isn't always displayed, sometmies it just stays white without any content. When I try and inspect the overlay, my code is loaded.
What could be the problem?

I've added some screenshots to show the problem:

Working options page:
[image: Working options page]

Working source code:
[image: Working source code]

Not working options page:
[image: Not working options page]

Not working source code:
[image: Not working source code]

Comment: No, no errors are displayed. This problem happens quite often when I try to open the page. Even when I haven't changed my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution in the provided url: [Issue 550217](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=550217#c10)

I've enabled my HWA and it's shows up a lot more now. Don't know if it really solved the problem but it works for now.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known Chrome bug: [crbug.com/550217](https://crbug.com/550217)

Try forcing the page to redraw on load:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.body.style.webkitTransform = "scale(1)";
};
```